# css textbox with a floating button beside it

Tags: css

I'm working on a mobile template for my site and I want a textbox inside a div to be width:100% with an html submit button beside it, however the button always seems to wrap to the second line. Can someone help me out with some CSS for this?

```
<style type="text/css">
    .form_input {}
    .form_submit{}
</style>

<div>
    <input type="text" name="s" value="" class="form_input" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="form_submit" />
</div>
```

Comment: Does `.form_submit` need to be fixed width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrapping happens because of the workings of the css box model. `100%` means 100% of the context box. So the input field will fill the line completely -> the submit button has to wrap to the next line. You can give the input box a width of e.g. 80% and the submit button a width of 20%.

I guess what you really want to do is something like input{ width: 100% - 200px }, submit {width: 200px}. That is not possible with css2.

Comment: I was hoping there was some magical css2 for this but oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Set the div to position:relative; and then set both the textbox and submit button to absolute position:

```
div.box{ position:relative; }

input[type="text"]{position:absolute;left:0;top:0;}
input[type="submit"]{positon:absolute;right:0;top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the textbox to `width: 100%;`, then it will take up all the space available, and always push the submit button down.

This code specifies a width for both input elements:

```
.form_input {
  width: 70%;
}
.form_submit{
  width: 20%;
}
```

and they will be on the same line.  (70% + 20% = 90% because I've left a little room for margins.)